# Rendered Texture looks messed up

Tags: texturing, uv, normals, color

I could not figure this one out by myself so far, and would appreciate some assistance from you guys.

After setting up the base color / albedo and the normal map for my object, it looks fine in 3D view, but as soon as I switch into a rendered view or perform a render, the texture looks messed up.

Here is the 3D view:
[image]

and here the rendered view:
[image]

The .blend file if it helps:
http://www.filedropper.com/coucholdnew1

Thank you in advance guys!

-Aldin

Comment: I'll bet it's a UV issue. Can you post an image of your Mesh Data tab and material settings?

Comment: Hey Matt, I have uploaded the .blend file here if you want to take a look at it: http://www.pasteall.org/blend/41979

Comment: I'll see what I can do...

Comment: I downloaded the file but the textures are missing.

Comment: @Aldin textures do not get saved into the .blend file by default. You have to **pack** them. On the top menu select File>External Data>Pack All into File. Re-Save the file and upload again please. Otherwise folks downloading your file will get a pink texture.

Comment: And in the future consider using other hosting service other than pasteall.org . Links on that site expire after a few weeks and then others might not be able to learn from your file. You can use http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/ to upload. Then [edit] the resulting link into the original post.

Comment: Hi, Sorry, I packed the textures now into the .blend file. @cegaton thank you also for the recommendation for another hosting service. The packed file was unfortunately too big for exchange.giantcowfilms, so I uploaded it to the following instead: http://www.filedropper.com/coucholdnew1 -- hope this helps now!

Comment: I see it already with artifacts in 3d view and the render result is the same - also with artifacts. Inspecting the normal map shows already present artifacts in the texture and also normals not pointing in the same direction on the mesh. So inspect normals and bake a new normal map. You should bake it to a smoothed surface so each vertex has only 1 normal.

Comment: Definitely a problem with the baked nmap, as @Jerryno stated. If you turn off the normal map the artifacts are gone.
I check the normals and they are fine, and I tried cloning the nmap but the artifacts are still there. Maybe it is a bug with the tangent normal map in BI.

Comment: The normal map is fine, I tried to render the scene in cycles creating a simple shader (diffuse with normal map) and no artifacts are shown. I'm suspecting it's a bug in the  BI renderer

Comment: ...A bug or simply a limitation of the renderer. Those artifacts are showing along some UV seams.
The UV work in this model could use more love. The seams are placed awkwardly, making these issues more visible. With a little work there those artifacts would end in places where they aren't visible.

Comment: thank you so much guys :) changing the color space to "non color" as Bithur (see accepted answer) fixed the issue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Changing the color space of your normal map texture to "Non-Color" should fix your problem
[image: non-color]

Normal maps are not color, they are values. Using the non-color space makes blender use the values stored, not the corresponding color.
[More about color spaces in Blender](https://www.blender.org/manual/render/post_process/cm_and_exposure.html).

Comment: Thank you so much, that worked! :) also thanks for the information about normal maps!

Answer (score 0):

I checked your file and your geometry seems to be ok (no verts facing the wrong direction). It turns out that this is caused by the normal texture (which I already suspected quietly). If you turn it off the model comes out quite nicely. It almost looks like the normals on the affected faces are turned 180 degrees.

Errors in normal maps happen, if you bake the normal map from a model that consists of several submeshes, while they are close to each other, but that would look more noticeably stranger than your normal texture.

Since there is no high poly model with geometry that resembles the fabric I suppose that you've created your normal texture from the diffuse texture so I guess the error was produced by whatever software you used for that.

Comment: hey, i baked the normal map from a high poly mesh in the software "Substance Painter 2". Thank you for the information and analysis! :)