# Problem when baking normal map

Tags: normal-map

I'm new into textures and I'm trying to bake high res normal map for low res model. And I always get same result, this distortion on the places where seams are. Any help?

[image]

[image]

I'm trying to use cage method, so my low res is bigger than high res, if I leave the same size result is the same. I feel like it is very stupid and tiny mistake, please help!

Comment: check [this](http://blender.stackexchange.com/a/53146/11431)

Comment: Have you tried to increase the Bias value?

Comment: dint help unfortunately

Comment: Do you mind uploading your file to http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/ ?