# Normal baking corner problem

Tags: normals, texture-baking, baking, normal-map

Good evening!

*I've looked at other similar topics but none resolved my issue.*

The problem is corners after baking normals and applying them to a mesh.

Both cubes have same amount of bevel. 
I have subdivided only 5 large square faces and sculpted them for the High res. cube.

Unwraped with smart UV

What could be the problem?

[image: Problem]

[image: Settings]

[image]

Comment: Problem looks similar to this: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/53025/rendered-texture-looks-messed-up/53146#53146

But the normal is already non-color.

Comment: Try increasing *Margin* in the Bake options for normal map (if it wasn't already).

Comment: Tried margin of 0, 3, 16, 64 .. Doesn't help..

Comment: Does the mesh have doubles / any not expected geometry ? Also make sure that UV map islands don't intersect and have enough space between them. Maybe [upload it](http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/) and add a link here

Comment: @Mr Zak Thanks for Your time! Here is the project: [<img src="http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/embedImage.png?bid=2316" />](http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/2316/)

Comment: Well, problem is definitely not the non-color data.. rather than the topology of your high-poly mesh, and maybe UV map for the low-poly cube. I'm really unaware how that cube can make Smart UV Project fail like it does, but anyway big faces of your cube intersect with bevels (not desired), although the main problem is high-poly I will try to elaborate in answer if it goes well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem are the ngons with 124 vertices/edges on the high res cube.

[image: 124 verts ngon]

Adding a triangulate modifier to the cube solves that issue.

Also, the front and bottom faces of the low res cube are overlapped in the UV, so you should unwrap it again.